# Is the opposite direction to prenex normal form decidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Lets say that $\phi$ is written in a Prenex**ed** form, if it is in prenex normal form and there is a formula $\phi^*$ that is not in prenex normal form such that $\phi^*$ is equivalent to $\phi$ and $\phi^*$ results from mere pulling in of some quantifiers in the prefix of $\phi$ to the inside of $\phi$, with or without change of quantifier symbols (i.e.; $\forall$ to $\exists$ or $\exists$ to $\forall$) during that pulling.

For example:  $\forall x (\neg \phi)$ ..Pull in $\forall x$ but convert it to $\exists x$ during the pulling to have $ (\neg \exists x \phi)$. Also $\exists x (\phi \to \psi)$ ..Pull in $\exists x$ and turn it into $\forall x $ during the pulling to have $(\forall x \phi \to \psi)$.

Now I want to coin a syntactical notion of *pure non-Prenexed form* to mean that the formula is not in Prenexed form, nor is any of its subformulas.

Is that notion decidable?

Comment: How can it be possible that non of a formulas subformulas are in prenex normal form?  The leaves of the AST will always be in PNF.  A possible alternative definition would be "a formula is in the image of the unprenexing algorithm" but then you'd have to define the algorithm much more precisely.

Comment: @DanielV, ...in prenex**ed** form..., and not in ...prenex normal form... There is a difference! You can have a formula that is in prenex normal form, but it is not in prenexed form, example $y=y$ also $\exists y (y = y)$, those are NOT prenexed forms